# Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**When running the following code I get a syntax error:**

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?")
if userAnswer = ("yes")
    { console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!") }
else { console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'") }
```

There is more code than the lines above but I know the error originates from there.

Comment: `if userAnswer = ("yes")` <--- what's this? Where did you find such an odd syntax for `if`?

Comment: change with: `if (userAnswer == "yes")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` syntax is wrong. It should be this instead:

```
if (userAnswer === "yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if-then syntax seems wrong, it should be `if (expression) {} else {}`. You're also using an assignment operator in the if expression (`userAnswer = ("yes")`) instead of testing for equality (`userAnswer == "yes"`)

Try the following:

```
if (userAnswer == "yes") {
    console.log("You and Bieber...")
}
else {
    console.log("Oh no! ...")
}
```